# How to get SEID or Secure Element Id in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get the SEID or known as Secure Element Id programmatically in Objective-C.

I know I can get the `UUID` from `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]` but this is not the one I'm looking for.

The **SEID** is the one located on **Settings** -> **General** -> **About** -> **SEID**.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Ended up using a unique id generated in the backend that is specific to each user. But, we couldn't use the SEID to match user with the same device and not another device.

Comment: What is your use case?  If anyone could retrieve this, wouldn't it defeat the purpose of the SEID being **Secure**?

Comment: Mm.. yeah maybe. I can't really talk in details what is it for but, it's for a matching implementation that we need to match the user with our database records and the backend guys get this SEID from Apple somehow and they want to match with the device is doing the request..

Comment: It is not possible. That is why it is called as secure element ID.

Comment: I think Apple would consider that abuse.  But if you really want to go down that rabbit hole, I'd recommend checking out the classes in the private NanoPassKit framework, specifically [`NPKProtoRemoteAdminPerformRequest`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/NanoPassKit.framework/NPKProtoRemoteAdminPerformRequest.h).

Comment: Thank you so much @JAL!!! I will try to raise this to Apple and see if they agreed with us to use this..